# How to create function to create array of keys?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array of users:

```
const users =[ 
   { 
      id:1,
      name:'bob',

   },
   { 
      id:2,
      name:'sally',

   },
   { 
      id:3,
      name:'bob',
      age:30,

   }
];
```

Now I want to extract the keys by either name,id or age(example for name):

```
const arrangeByName = arrangeBy('name'); 
arrangeByName(users);
```

So the result would be:

```
['bob','sally'];
```

My arrangeBy function looks like this:

```
const go = A => key => {
  return A.map(a => a.key);
};
export default go;
```

But when I run this I get:

```
A.map is not a function
```

How can I write a function that can extract keys in an array? Also note that any duplicates are not created in the output.

Comment: Where are you calling `go`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to exclude objects for which the given key property is not present, and want to exclude duplicates, things become a little more complex.

This solution filters out the objects for which the property is not present, and uses a `Set` to avoid duplicates:

```
const arrangeBy = key => A => [...A.reduce((s, v) => key in v ? s.add(v[key]) : s, new Set())];
```

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const users = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'bob',
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'sally',

}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'bob',
  age: 30,

}];

const arrangeBy = key => A => [...A.reduce((s, v) => key in v ? s.add(v[key]) : s, new Set())];

const arrangeByName = arrangeBy('name');
const arrangeByAge = arrangeBy('age');

console.log(arrangeByName(users));
console.log(arrangeByAge(users));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues. One, your arguments are in the wrong order as it seems you want `arrangeBy` to accept a key and return a function that accepts users. Second, `a.key` will try to access a property called "key" on the object, which I doubt is what you are trying to do - you will instead want to do `a[key]`

```js
// get values of key, removing duplicates
const arrangeBy = key => arr => 
  [...arr.reduce((set, el) => set.add(el[key]), new Set)]
const arrangeByName = arrangeBy('name')
const arrangeById = arrangeBy('id')

const users = [{id: 1, name: 'bob'}, {id: 2, name: 'sally'}, {id: 3, name: 'bob'}]

console.log(arrangeByName(users))
console.log(arrangeById(users))
```

Comment: What if I have this as users:[ 
   { 
      id:1,
      name:'bob',

   },
   { 
      id:2,
      name:'sally',

   },
   { 
      id:3,
      name:'bob',
      age:30,

   }
]? I get ['bob','sally','bob']. How to avoid the duplicate?

Comment: @bierhier this is based on the function you supplied and simply intends to correct the errors you would encounter with your implementation. If you are expecting different behavior, (removal of duplicates?) you should specify the exact intended behavior of the function.

Comment: @bierhier edited to include removal of duplicates since that seems to be the intended behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Array.prototype.arrangeBy`:

```js
Array.prototype.arrangeBy = function(key) {
  const array = this
    .filter(el => !!el[key])
    .map(el => el[key])
  return [...new Set(array)]
}

const users = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'bob'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'sally'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'bob',
    age: 30
  }
]

console.log(users.arrangeBy('id'))
console.log(users.arrangeBy('name'))
console.log(users.arrangeBy('age'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function arangeByKey(key) {
   return function (arr) {
      return arr.map(item => item[key]);
   };
}


const arangeByName = arangeByKey('name');
const arrangeById = arangeByKey('id');

console.log(arangeByName(users));
console.log(arrangeById(users));

// If array contains unique element
console.log([... new Set(arangeByName(users))]);
```